# Write a function that accepts a list of strings and concatenates them

Tags: python, string, concatenation

> Write a function called concat() that takes a list of strings as an
> argument and returns a single string that is all the items in the list
> concatenated (put side by side). (Note that you may not use the join()
> function.)
>
> Sample run:
>
> ```
> print( concat(['a', 'bcd', 'e', 'fg']) )
> abcdefg
> ```

Comment: If you were shown `'con' + 'cat'`, what exactly do you not understand with this or the output created?

Comment: I'd personally recommend asking your teacher for help on this - this seems a really, really, daft request to make on their behalf... they must have some reasoning for it (well, I'd hope so anyway) - so not sure what they're actually asking you to discover here/do here.

Comment: I'm confused about what specifically you're asking, but also I'm really confused about why anyone would give this as an assignment. It doesn't make any sense in Python to write your own concatenation function.

Comment: The thing was, she never explained any of this, I have no idea what concats are and I don't know how to apply it to the code. I am only a beginner, so I still am really confused on most things.

Comment: @Amira then I'd personally be somewhat worried about the quality of the education you're receiving... again - although I believe you've got the answer that you're probably expected to have produced - I'm concerned for you.

Comment: The thing is, teachers are not required to spoon-feed evertything. You can start at the official Python documentation and learn far faster than your teacher will teach... For example - [string concatenation is discussed here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) and you can also learn about defining functions later there too

Comment: Nothing in the question presupposes knowledge of the term "concat". They could have said to write a function named "abracadabra" that does the same thing. (And implementing an existing function as a *coding exercise* is hardly "daft"; the fact that you could simply write `concat = ''.join` gives you a quick way to determine if your version of `concat` is working or not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you can just use the `+` operator to concatenate two strings. In your case, you can do something like this:

```
def concat(list_args):
    res = ""
    for w in list_args:
        res += w
    return res
```

Then if you run

```
print(concat(['a', 'bcd', 'e', 'fg']))
```

you get `abcdefg`

Comment: Keep in mind, this is far from the most performant option

Comment: @OneCricketeer correct. Since strings are immutable, using `+=` especially on a very large list will be terribly inefficient. OP did not include any time or space constraints though, and this seems like an introductory question

Comment: The most performant version would be to use `''.join`, which is what the OP was told *not* to do. Presumably, this is exactly what the teacher had in mind, in terms of basic manipulation of lists and strings.